# Auction/Bids in Firestore: Handle concurrent writes

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am implementing an auction process in Firestore and so far, everything works fine. Each auction item has a deadline and until the time runs out, user are able to bid on the item. The user with the highest bid wins.

However, I wonder how I can handle multiple users bidding at the same time for an item. At the moment I have a collection ("auction_item") which saves the highest bid and the user accordingly. When a user bids in the app, I make sure that the bid is higher than the current highest bid and then save the user and the latest bid.

I fear that multiple users bidding at the same time will cause multiple bids with the same amount in the collection. How do I prevent that in Firestore?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is to support an atomic operation to ensure that the writing of the bid from any of the users is done always with up-to-date and consistent data.

Firestore supports this kind of operation through [transactions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions):

> Cloud Firestore supports atomic operations for reading and writing data. In a set of atomic operations, either all of the operations succeed, or none of them are applied.
>
> Transactions: a transaction is a set of read and write operations on one or more documents.

Please note that when using `transactions` the following applies:

> Read operations must come before write operations.
>
> - A function calling a transaction (transaction function) might run more than once if a concurrent edit affects a document that the transaction reads.
> - Transaction functions should not directly modify application state.
> - Transactions will fail when the client is offline.

Depending on the scenario, a `transaction` might have a performance impact, as the function might run more than once in case of concurrent edits.

Comment: Hi,

Thank you very much!

So basically, I start a transaction every time a user bids:

Transaction: Read current value and check if ok -> Write.

If another user bids at the same time, the transaction will run again, until both of them are finished.

Did I get that right?